# laravel Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Tags: php, laravel

i have permissions for this role and other permission that this role don't have i want to display both permission in this role and other ones in the same page separated heres index in my controller

```
public function index(Request $request , $id,$permission_id)
{
    $rolepermission =DB::table('permission_role')
        ->join('permissions', 'permissions.id', '=', 'permission_role.permission_id')
        ->where('permission_role.role_id' , $id)
        ->get();

    $rolepermissiongetid =DB::table('permission_role')->select('role_id')
        ->where('permission_role.role_id' , $id)
        ->get();

    $notrolepermision =DB::table('permission_role')
        ->join('permissions', 'permissions.id', '=', 'permission_role.permission_id')
        ->whereNotIn('permission_role.role_id' ,$rolepermissiongetid)
        ->get();



    $nodata = '';
    if($rolepermission==null){
        $nodata="This Roles Does Not Have Permissions";
    }

    $role=DB::table('roles')->where('id' ,$id)->first();

    return view('managements.role-permission-list')
        ->with('role' ,$role)
        ->with('data' , $rolepermission)
        ->with('role2', $notrolepermision)
        ->with('nodata' , $nodata)
        ->with('role_id' ,$id);
}
```

but i keep getting  Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string,

i did foreach to get the data in my view

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            @foreach($role2 as $role2s)
                <button class="btn btn-primary">{{$role2s->name}}</button>

             @endforeach

            <!-- /.panel-heading -->
            <div class="panel-body">
        @if(isset($success_alert))
            <div class="alert alert-success">{{$success_alert}}</div>
        @endif
        @if(isset($danger_alert))
            <div class="alert alert-danger">{{$danger_alert}}</div>
        @endif


            @foreach($data as $dat)


                <div class="col-lg-3">
                    <button class="btn btn-default">{{$dat->name}}</button>
                    <hr>
                </div>


              <!--      <td>
                        <a href='/role-permission-confirm-delete/{{$dat->role_id}}/{{$dat->permission_id}}' class='btn btn-danger'><i class='fa fa-close'></i> Delete</a>

                       <!-- <a href='/role-permission/{{$dat->role_id}}/{{$dat->permission_id}}' class='btn btn-warning confirm'> View </a>
                    </td>-->

            @endforeach


        <!-- /.table-responsive -->

    </div>
        </div>
   <!-- <a href="/role-permission/create/{{$role->id}}" class="btn btn-primary">
        <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> New Permission
    </a> -->
</div>
</div>
```

this im getting with the error

> Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string
>   in RolePermissionsController.php line 32
>   at HandleExceptions->handleError('8', 'Trying to get property of non-object', 'C:\xampp\htdocs\terkwazmng\app\Http\Controllers\RolePermissionsController.php', '32', array('role_id' => '1', 'rolepermission' => array(object(stdClass), object(stdClass), object(stdClass), object(stdClass), object(stdClass), object(stdClass), object(stdClass), object(stdClass), object(stdClass), object(stdClass), object(stdClass), object(stdClass), object(stdClass), object(stdClass), object(stdClass), object(stdClass), object(stdClass), object(stdClass), object(stdClass), object(stdClass), object(stdClass), object(stdClass), object(stdClass), object(stdClass), object(stdClass), object(stdClass), object(stdClass), object(stdClass), object(stdClass), object(stdClass), object(stdClass), object(stdClass), object(stdClass), object(stdClass), object(stdClass), object(stdClass), object(stdClass), object(stdClass), object(stdClass), object(stdClass), object(stdClass), object(stdClass), object(stdClass), object(stdClass), object(stdClass), object(stdClass), object(stdClass)), 'rolepermissiongetid' => array(object(stdClass), object(stdClass), object(stdClass), object(stdClass), object(stdClass), object(stdClass), object(stdClass), object(stdClass), object(stdClass), object(stdClass), object(stdClass), object(stdClass), object(stdClass), object(stdClass), object(stdClass), object(stdClass), object(stdClass), object(stdClass), object(stdClass), object(stdClass), object(stdClass), object(stdClass), object(stdClass), object(stdClass), object(stdClass), object(stdClass), object(stdClass), object(stdClass), object(stdClass), object(stdClass), object(stdClass), object(stdClass), object(stdClass), object(stdClass), object(stdClass), object(stdClass), object(stdClass), object(stdClass), object(stdClass), object(stdClass), object(stdClass), object(stdClass), object(stdClass), object(stdClass), object(stdClass), object(stdClass), object(stdClass)))) in RolePermissionsController.php line 32

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue would be with this piece of code, $role2s is an object. Since you are trying to print the object it is throwing the error

```
<button class="btn btn-primary">{{$role2s}}</button>
```

Trying running var_dump on the particular variable.

Comment: i get Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string error in the view page, and i changed {{$role2s}} to {{$role2s->name}} kept getting the same error

Comment: Please share the entire view page content as well as error message you are getting

Answer (score 1):

Try to do this:
it works 100%

```
$rolepermissiongetid =DB::table('permission_role')->select('role_id')
 ->where('permission_role.role_id' , $id)
    ->get();




$arrQuery = array();
foreach($rolepermissiongetid as $key => $rolepermissiongetid){
$arrQuery[$key] = rolepermissiongetid->role_id;
 }




$notrolepermision =DB::table('permission_role')
    ->join('permissions', 'permissions.id', '=', 'permission_role.permission_id')
    ->whereNotIn('permission_role.role_id' ,$arrQuery)
    ->get();



//tunisian_developpers_team
```

Answer (score 0):

curly braces are equals to PHP's echo statement. In $role2s variable you are getting object/array so it'll not print but give you an error. So you can use below solution. and after that  **->**  or  **[' ']**  get it's object or array.

Try

> **{{dd($role2s)}}**

or

> **{{print_r({{$role2s}})}}**

or

> **{{var_dump({{$role2s}})}}**

**

Comment: i know i used that the problem is not from the view but the controller

Answer (score 0):

You don't have specify your exact error. But May be error is in controller. check code below

```
$notrolepermision =DB::table('permission_role')
        ->join('permissions', 'permissions.id', '=', 'permission_role.permission_id')
        ->whereNotIn('permission_role.role_id' ,$rolepermissiongetid->role_id) //<--------------check this line you need $rolepermissiongetid->role_id in stead of $rolepermissiongetid
        ->get();
```

Comment: i have $rolepermissiongetid =DB::table('permission_role')->select('role_id')
        ->where('permission_role.role_id' , $id)
        ->get(); so no need to use $rolepermissiongetid->role_id